# React native Tab View congested when number of tab is increase

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-tab-view, react-native-scrollable-tab-view

I am using `react-native-tab-view` for display tab on the top of the screen. Screen view looks congested in case of number of screen is going to increase (more than 5)

Below is my code snippet

```
export default class CustomTabViewComponent extends React.Component{
state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'tab1', title: 'Tab1' },
      { key: 'tab2', title: 'Tab2' },
      { key: 'tab3', title: 'Tab3' },
      { key: 'tab4', title: 'Tab4' },
      { key: 'tab5', title: 'Tab5' },
    ],
  };
render(){
   return(
   <TabView
          navigationState={this.state}
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          renderTabBar={this._renderTabBar}
          onIndexChange={this.onIndexChange}
          initialLayout={{
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
            height: 100,
          }}
        />

)}
}
```

I am posting image also for reference.

[image]

Is there any property with the help of that i can make `TabView` scrollable to the right with individual tab fix width ?

PS: I have try `react-native-scrollable-tab-view` but stuck at the same place.

Answer (score 9):

pass `renderTabBar` prop to TableView which returns a custom React Element and return `<TabBar>`, add `tabStyle` and `scrollEnabled={true}` to `TabBar`.

> **renderTabBar** - Callback which returns a custom React Element to use as the tab bar
>
> **TabBar** - Material design themed tab bar.
>
> **scrollEnabled** - Boolean indicating whether to enable scrollable tabs.
>
> **tabStyle** - Style to apply to the individual tab items in the tab bar.

```
import { TabView, SceneMap, TabBar } from 'react-native-tab-view';

<TabView
  navigationState={this.state}
  renderScene={this.renderScene}
  renderTabBar={this._renderTabBar}
  onIndexChange={this.onIndexChange}
  renderTabBar={props => (
    <TabBar
      {...props}
      indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
      tabStyle={{ width: 100 }}
      scrollEnabled={true}
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
    />
  )}
  initialLayout={{
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: 100,
  }}
/>
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/react-native-tab-view-expo-example)